# angularjs: for two different links, only one video is displayed for both links, not two videos

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, video

There were 1 video (the first part of the code below) that works fine and as expected: video is displayed if you click on the image.

```
<div class="video1" data-ng-init="item = {src:  'http://www.youtube.com/embed/xwidefc2wpc?html5=1'}">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-dvs-modal="getThemeUrl('/views/video.html')" data-ng-click="showModal()"><img alt="video1" data-ng-src="{{getContentUrl('/images/video1img.jpg')}}" /></a>
</div>
```

I would like one more video on the html page. That's why I placed this code right below the code above:

```
<div class="video2" data-ng-init="item = {src:  'http://www.youtube.com/embed/8pGTgkcP-RU?html5=1'}">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-dvs-modal="getThemeUrl('/views/video.html')" data-ng-click="showModal()"><img alt="video2" data-ng-src="{{getContentUrl('/images/video2img.jpg')}}" /></a>
</div>
```

However, instead of displaying both videos with the updated code, the page displays the second video when I click on ANY of this two links.
Could anybody please explain what should be changed the code above? I'm new to angular with this code.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks to me like there both invoking `data-ng-click="showModal()"` with no specific argument to determine which video it is. What is this method doing?

Comment: show the code for `showModal()`